# Orthogonal projection onto subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{C}^4$ with the standard vector multiplication we set $W = span\{ (1,-i,2+i,2-i),(-i,-i,0,0),(2-2i,-2-i,5,3-2i)\}$ and the question is to find the orthogonal projection of $v=(i,i,i,i)$ onto $W$.

First using Gram-Shcmidt method i got an orthogonal base for $W$ which is :

$W = span \{  (1,-i,2+i,2-i) ,(-\frac{1}{12} - \frac{11 i}{12}, \frac{1}{12} - \frac{11 i}{12}, -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{i}{12}, -\frac{1}{12} + \frac{i}{4}), (\frac{8}{11} - i, -\frac{8}{11} + i, \frac{15}{22} - \frac{5 i}{22}, \frac{5}{22} + \frac{29 i}{22})\}$,

Now i can use the method :

$ E_W(v) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{3} \frac{<v,u_i>}{||u_i||^2 } u_i$ and i got the answer :

$ E_W(v) =(\frac{8}{59} + \frac{65 i}{59}, -\frac{8}{59} + \frac{53 i}{59}, -\frac{11}{59} + \frac{47 i}{59}, \frac{11}{59} + \frac{
 61 i}{59}) $

but the answer in the book is $ \frac{-7+6i}{124-110i} (-10i,-10i,-9-2i,5)$

Where i got wrong ? , please reply

Comment: Without your showing more of your work, you’re just asking us to guess.

Comment: @amd i did show the steps with the final result, is my way for solving this question correct ?

Comment: @amd or could you show the right way to solve such questions ?

Comment: There is quite a bit of computation missing between where you’ve written “Now i can use the method...” and the result of that computation. Anyway, I would suggest checking that you’ve read the book’s answer correctly since what you’ve got in your question isn’t even an element of $W$. It could well be an error in your book. You can also check your own answer by verifying that $v-E_W(v)$ is orthogonal to the given spanning vectors.